# Relacionamento Infinito....?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho uma duvida que seria, como realizar um relacionamento que pode ser infinito.: 
Ex:

Tabela user com o campo user id que seria um pra muitos com Tabela Post.

Dentro da Tabela Post teria post_id que teria mais post dentro dele.

Tabela Post com campos ( User_id, Post_id, Text ).
Tabela Post2 com campos ( User_id, Post2_id, Post2_postID, Text ).

No cenario acima se tivesse mais 10 post usaria mais 10 tabelas post.

há alguma maneiro de ter esse relacionamentos.

Com comparativo seria uma arvore de diretorios que dentro de cada um posso ter quantos diretorios quiser e arquivos.

Comment: Sidiclei F. Almeida, eu acredito que você esteja falando de um "auto-relacionamento". Segue exemplos:

Comment: [Aulas‎ > ‎10 - Auto-Relacionamentos ](https://sites.google.com/site/uniplibancodedados1/aulas/aula-9---auto-relacionamentos) [Auto-Relacionamentos em Bancos de Dados Relacionais](https://ericlemes.com/2009/01/27/bd-autorelacionamento/) [Relacionamentos em um Banco de Dados](https://www.diegomacedo.com.br/relacionamentos-em-um-banco-de-dados/)

Comment: Pode da fazer 1:N ou até auto relacionamento. Eu indicaria duas tabelas no site já tem resposta pra essas duas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa apenas ter uma tabela chamada `post`:

```
id
post_id
user_id
text
```

Quando um determinado `post` nao tiver outro post dentro dele, você deve definir `post_id` como `NULL`.

Já no seu model insira os seguinte relacionamentos:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}

public function todosOsPosts()
{
    return $this->posts()->with('todosOsPosts');
}
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26654139/8828706

Comment: Ola, a resposta acima deu certo porem surgiu uma duvida.. estou tentando fazer a que post pertence o post.. exemplo hoje "post x pertente ao y " se para fazer o inverso " post y depende do x"

Comment: o inverso seria o belongsTo, sabe usar ?

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada Obrigado...

Comment: de uma olhada nessa pergunta que fiz sobre esse auto-relacinamento... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/354430/resultado-de-relacionamento-com-auto-relacionamento